# What classes of graphs result from $\overline{T}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I need help in characterizing the classes of graphs that results from taking the complementary of a tree, i.e., the graph that results from removing the edges of a tree from a complete graph. More formally, let $T=(V,E)$ be an $n$-vertex tree with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$. Are there known results on the classes of graphs defined by $\overline{T}$?

There are two trivial cases. If $T=S_n$, i.e., is a star tree (one single vertex has degree $n-1$ and the other vertices have degree $1$), we have that $\overline{S_n}=\{v\}\cup K_{n-1}$, i.e., $\overline{S_n}$ is a graph with an isolate vertex (degree $0$) and a $(n-1)$-vertex clique. I've got the feeling that $\overline{P_n}$ (where $P_n$ is an $n$-vertex path graph) has a precise characterization but I can't put a name to it.

If there are no (or few) results about general $T$, can we say something about $\overline{T}$ if $T$ belongs to a class of trees, for example caterpillar trees (trees in which the removal of all leaves produces a path graph), lobster trees (trees in which the removal of all leaves produces a caterpillar tree), ...?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: I also posted this on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415193/what-classes-of-graphs-result-from-overlinet).

Comment: I don't think there is any description of "complements of trees" that is *simpler* than "complements of trees". Is there a more concrete problem you're trying to apply this to?

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear what kind of characterization you are looking for. Here's one: complements of trees are the maximal graphs not containing a complete bipartite graph as a spanning subgraph. That is, maximal graphs that do not contain a subgraph of the  form $K_{s,t}$, where $s+t$ is the number of vertices of the graph. Indeed, a graph is connected if and only if its complement does not contain a subgraph of this form. Since trees are the minimal connected graphs, their complements are the maximal graphs with this property.

Comment: Hi, I'm not looking for anything particular. Just results and as much information I can get to learn and apply it the best I can. The one you've given, for example, is really nice! Do you happen to have a reference to the claim?

Comment: [At mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/415193/150321), I was pointed to [this resource about complements of path graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathComplementGraph.html).

Comment: I need some more details in your answer though. If $T$ is an $n$-vertex tree, then you say that $\overline{T}$ does not contain $K_{n,n}$ as a subgraph, right? Could you update the first paragraph with *a bit more* notation? Thanks!

Comment: I was indeed a bit careless in my answer. I've updated my answer to be a bit more precise. I don't know a reference for this, but it is an easy exercise to prove.

Comment: $\overline P_n$ is *not* the unique graph with that degree sequence, just as $P_n$ is not the unique graph with degree sequence $2, 2, \dots, 2, 1, 1$. For instance, $K_{2,3}$ has the same degree sequence as $\overline P_5$, and $K_{3,3}$ with a single edge added has the same degree sequence as $\overline P_6$.

Comment: You are right, of course. I was thinking about complements of connected graphs.